# HeapValidate Fails

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I'm trying to build up a structure like this

```
typedef struct elements {
    struct elements *next;
    int key;
    struct value *val;
};

typedef struct dict
{
    struct dict_elements **dictionary_head;
};

typedef struct value
{
    int val;
};
```

The structure is created like this

```
box->dictionary_head = (struct elements**)malloc(sizeof(struct elements*) * DICT_SIZE);
```

and I insert an element like this

```
int DictInsert(struct dictionary_box *box, int key, struct value* value)
{
    temp = (struct elements*) malloc(sizeof(struct elements*));
    temp->key = key;
    temp->val = value;
    temp->next = NULL;
    box->dictionary_head[1] = temp;
}
```

but when i go to remove the element in this way

```
void DictRemove(struct dictionary_box *box, MHANDLE key)
{ 
    struct elements *next = box->dictionary_head[1]->next;
    free((box->dictionary_head[1])->val);
    free(box->dictionary_head[1]);  <<<-----------HeapValidate Assert failure
    box->dictionary_head[1] = next;
....
}
```

it crashes saying that this value is not on the heap....what I'm doing wrong? I've tried everything but I really don't understand where I'm wrong.

At the moment I'm just doing an Insert() and a Remove() but I'm stuck on this error.

EDIT1:
    struct dictionary_box box;

```
void Insert(int value)
{
    struct value* test;
    test =(struct value*)malloc(sizeof(struct value));
    test->val = val;
    DictInsert(&box, value, test);
}

int main(){
    CreateDictionary(&box);
    Insert(1);
    DictRemove(&box, 1);
    DeleteDictionary(&box);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try to come up with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You've selectively given us some code (and not even the real code as `value` is not a valid field in the struct). The problem may not even be where you think it is.

Comment: `temp = (struct elements*) malloc(sizeof(struct elements*));` does not allocate the right amount of memory. It needs `sizeof(struct elements)`.

Comment: Is there a `struct dict_elements` defined somewhere else in your program, or do you in fact mean `struct dict.dictionary_head` to have type `struct elements **`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code for inserting an element looks suspect:

```
temp = (struct elements*) malloc(sizeof(struct elements*));
...fill the values...
```

I think you want sizeof(struct elements), not the size of the pointer:

```
temp = (struct elements*) malloc(sizeof(struct elements));
...fill the values...
```

Comment: Or even better, `temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));`

Comment: Ok, now seems to work, it was just a size problem...I can't believe I've lost 3 hours for a problem like this, thanks